# An $n$-norm for the space of continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Given a (real) vector space $F$ of dimension $\geq n$, recall that  $\|\cdot,\ldots,\cdot\|:F^{n}\longrightarrow [0,\infty)$ satisfying the following conditions for each $x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\in F$:

(1) $\|x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\|=0$ if, and only if, $x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}$ are linear dependent.

(2) $\|x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\|$ is invariant under permutation.

(3)  $\| \lambda x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\|=|\lambda | \|x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\|$ for every $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

(4) $\|x_{0}+x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\|\leq \|x_{0},\ldots,x_{n}\|+\|x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\|$.

is said to be an $n$-norm on $F$, and the pair $(F,\|\cdot,\ldots,\cdot\|)$ a $n$-normed space.

For instance, if $F:=\mathbb{R}^{d}$, with $d\geq n$, then
$\|x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\|:=\sqrt{ \mathrm{det}\big(\langle x_{i},x_{j} \rangle  \big) }$ is an $n$-norm in $F$.

How can we define an $n$-norm in the linear space $F$ of the continuous functions $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$? I am thinking about a mapping of the form:
$$\|f_{1},\ldots,f_{n}\|:= \sup\left\{ \left|\, \mathrm{det}\left[ \begin{array}{l} f_{1}(x_{1}) & \cdots &f_{n}(x_{n}) \\ f_{1}(x_{1}) &\cdots &f_{n}(x_{n}) \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ f_{1}(x_{1})&\cdots& f_{n}(x_{n})   \end{array}\right] \,\right|:x_{1},\ldots,x_{n} \in [0,1]\right\}$$

which (from the properties of the determinant) it seems that obeys the conditions (2)-(4) of the above definition. I am not sure if the condition (1) holds. What do you think? Do you known some $n$-norm in this space $F$?

Many thanks in advance for your comments and suggestions.

Comment: I edited your post to improve the formatting a little. Please feel free to revise my edit, or to roll back to a previous version, if my edit did not improve your post.

Comment: Thanks for your corrections!

Comment: How are the $x_i$ defined? $\| f_1, \ldots,f_n\|$ clearly depends on the $x_i$, however they are not part of the vectors $f_i$. You would have to fix the $x_i$ in advance, however then (1) is clearly not fulfilled, as the polynomial $f_i = \Pi (x-x_i)$ will always have norm 0, while not being 0 itself.

Comment: All the functions $f_{1},\ldots,f_{n}$ are single variable. The $x_{i}$ are points in the inteval $[0,1]$, and are not "fixed", because ofr each selection of these points, the determinant will be different, in general.   For $n=2$, you can use the notation $f_{1}(x),f_{2}(y)$, with $x,y \in [0,1]$.